# Cannot retrieve created table from Azure Database in Visual Studios

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-sql-database

So, I followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-how-to-use-client-library) and what I am trying to do is simple. Create a client connection to Azure Database and simply read the contents in the page. I followed the quickstart document to the letter and downloaded a pre-made zip file containing an already made cordova app that connects to Azure. The project connects to Azure and it reads a table called todoitem. So the next thing I wanted to do was create a simple table within that database, so I created a simple table with an ID and a string. The problem? When I change the tableName var to the name of the table, for some reason, it dosen't do ANYTHING! It works for the already-made table but not the one I made! This is the code I am using...

```
var tableName = "newTable"
var client = WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(appUrl);  //ignore the appURL var
var table = client.getTable(tableName);

function success(results) {
    alert("The reading was a success");
    // my code here
}

function failure(error) {
    throw new Error('Error loading data: ', error);
}

table
    .read()
    .then(success, failure);
```

What I am SIMPLY doing is to check if the table is read at all. The problem is that for some reason, even when I put nothing but an alert to see if function success() was called, nothing happens. What is wierd is that if I changed the tableName back to "todoitem", which already came with the whole tutorial, it works perfect, but when I make my own table, no matte what I do, it just won't read the table or even just call either the sucess or failure functions....

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really have the data in your new table?  after creating the table did you insert any rows ?

Comment: Actually I finally fixed the problem. Apparently, you have to create the table via Easy Table in Azure Database website. Creating it in Visual Studios (despite being connected to the database) does not do anything since the database doesn't recognize that table because it lacks permission but when it is created by the website once you login, you are given permission to create tables.

Comment: Great to see that you've solved your problem. please provide your own answer and accept it,so that it can help others too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having trouble creating tables in Azure Database using Visual Studios, I found the problem. Apparently, you have to create the table via Easy Table in Azure Database website. Creating it in Visual Studios (despite being connected to the database) does not do anything. The table might be created and is shown in the Azure Database, but the database doesn't recognize that table because it lacks permission. So, when you log into your Azure Database and go find your Database, go to easy tables, there is where you can create your tables and gives permission to use it. To edit the data within the tables, such as inserting it, you can still use Visual Studios to enter data, but for some reason you can't add more columns/rows. Its recommended to do it in easy tables.